# Unable to login to remote computer after restart via teamviewer

Tags: 18.04, login, remote-desktop, teamviewer, anydesk

I'm accessing my lab PC from my laptop from home. I'm using either TeamViewer or Anydesk to access the remote computer. But since last few days, after a restart of remote computer, I'm not able to access the remote PC properly. In the sense, I am able to connect via TeamViewer or Anydesk. After connecting via TeamViewer, I can see the login screen of the remote PC. After I enter the system password, it logs me in and then everything freezes. The favorites on the dock are also not shown. Only TeamViewer and Anydesk windows are open and they are unresponsive too. At this point, someone has to physically restart the PC. In order for me to access the remote PC properly, someone has to physically be present at the PC and login (after restart). Is this a known problem? Is it possible to rectify this?

**More details**: We don't have UPS backup in lab and so whenever there is a power cut, PC shuts down. I've configured the PC to start automatically on AC power. Earlier, once it starts, I was able to login using TeamViewer or AnyDesk. But since few days, this new problem arose.